# What is the fastest way to sort some sort of list in c++?

Tags: c++, performance, list, sorting, data-structures

I have a struct

```
typedef struct  
{ 
    int id;  
    string name;  
    string address;
    string city;  
    // ...
} Customer;
```

I will have multiple customers so I need to store these structs in some sort of a list and then I need to sort by id.  There a probably multiple solutions here and I have a few ideas myself but I am looking for the best solution in terms of performance.

Comment: This question provides too few details for a meaningful answer to the request for "the best solution in terms of performance". What are you going to do with the sorted list? How often will you retrieve data from it? Will these retrievals be of the entire list, of a few known items, or of arbitrary items? How often will the data change? Do you need it sorted all the time?

Comment: I am going to use this list to display the information in a report, every time that the report is run, it will need to retrieve this data again and put it into the list so if the data changes, it will not matter because the work has to be done again every time

Comment: The fastest way is to send me the list. I'll sort it for you and send it back.

Comment: @wildplasser: yeah, you can sort the list in O(1) - I only have to send it once.

Comment: If it's economical to do so, you can maintain an index for each member of interest (e.g. in a `std::set<Customer*,CompareFunctor>`, remove and re-insert whenever you update a Customer) and traverse this in linear time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) provided by the stl algorithms package, example:

```
struct Customer {
    int id;
    Customer(int i) : id(i) {}
};

bool sortfunc(struct Customer i, struct Customer j) {
    return (i.id < j.id);
}

int main() {
    vector<Customer> customers;
    customers.push_back(Customer(32));
    customers.push_back(Customer(71));
    customers.push_back(Customer(12));
    customers.push_back(Customer(45));
    customers.push_back(Customer(26));
    customers.push_back(Customer(80));
    customers.push_back(Customer(53));
    customers.push_back(Customer(33));

    sort(customers.begin(), customers.end(), sortfunc);

    cout << "customers:";
    vector<Customer>::iterator it;
    for (it = customers.begin(); it != customers.end(); ++it)
        cout << " " << it->id;

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you storing Customers in std::set.

You should create operator <

```
bool Customer::operator < (const Customer& other) const {
    return id < customer.id;
}
```

Now, after each insert, collection is already sorted by id.

And you can iterate over whole collection by:

```
for(std::set<Customer>::iterator it = your_collection.begin(); it != your_collection.end(); it++)
```

This is fastest solution because you don't need to sort anything, and each insert takes O(log n) time.

Answer (score 0):

Using [std::list.sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/sort/) method should be the fastest way.

Comment: It may or may not be the fastest way, but it's what you should use anyway by default unless you have specific details about what order the list may already be in at the moment. This is assuming he is indeed using `std::list`.  But I think he was probably just using the word 'list' as a general term for a sequence container, not necessarily `std::list`.

Answer (score 0):

Define `operator<` for your structure to provide an ordering relation between `Customer` instances:

```
struct Customer {

    ...

    friend bool operator<(const Customer& a, const Customer& b) {
        return a.id < b.id;
    }

};
```

Use [this cheatsheet](http://linuxsoftware.co.nz/cppcontainers.html) (in particular the flowchart at the bottom) to decide which container you should use in your particular program. If it’s `std::set`, your sorting is done whenever you insert a `Customer` into the `set`. If it’s `std::list`, call the `sort()` member function on the list:

```
std::list<Customer> customers;
customers.push_back(Customer(...));
...
customers.sort();
```

If it’s `std::vector` or `std::deque`, use `std::sort()` from the `<algorithm>` header:

```
std::vector<Customer> customers;
customers.push_back(Customer(...));
...
std::sort(customers.begin(), customers.end());
```

If you need to sort in multiple ways, define a sorting function for each ordering:

```
struct Customer {

    ...

    static bool sort_by_name(const Customer& a, const Customer& b) {
        return a.name < b.name;
    }

};
```

Then tell `std::list::sort()` or `std::sort()` to use that comparator:

```
customers.sort(Customer::sort_by_name);

std::sort(customers.begin(), customers.end(), Customer::sort_by_name);
```